# Yii Variable Variables($$)

Tags: php, yii

How do I handle Variable Variable($$) in Active Record output?

For Ex.

```
$qdata = $qmodel->findByAttributes(array("q_id"=>$testqs[0]->q_id));
$qcorrect = "answer".$qdata->correct_answer;
```

I need `$qdata->answer1`. But the value 1 is dynamic based on what is passed.

`$qdata->$$qcorrect` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just one $ sign:

```
$qdata->$qcorrect
```